# how to filter a dataframe if a rows contains two values from a list in a column

Tags: python, database, pandas, dataframe, dataset

i need to filter a HUGE pandas dataframe that contains in the column 'A' two words from a list.
I already filtered it considering only a value from word_list, but i didnt figured it out how to do it for two values.

```
new_df = df[df["A"].apply(lambda x: any(i in x.split() for i in word_list))]
```

thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

You can do `explode` then `get_dummies`, `sum` by `level` then `sum` by columns , if row return value more than 2 , we should pick

```
df[df["A"].explode().str.get_dummies().\
     sum(level=0).gt(0).reindex(columns=word_list).sum(axis=1).ge(2)]
```

Or we can do `sklearn.MultiLabelBinarizer`

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
s=pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df['A']),columns=mlb.classes_, index=df.index)
df[s.sum(axis=1).gt(1)]
```

Comment: my code has to be fast, is there any way to do that using lambda?